# android 4.3 - BufferedReader shows Please Wait message

Tags: android

I have the following function to allow my android app to communicate with a web server. However the app shows a 'Please Wait' message when I call this code and only disappears if a new activity loads in or if I press the back button. Where is the Please wait coming from and how can I avoid it appearing? Thanks

```
package util.sapa.sapacontainermanager5;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class SimpleWebCalls {

    public String executeHttpGet(String serverIP, String nvp) {
        String lines="";
        serverIP="???????????";

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://" + serverIP + "/WCF.aspx?" + nvp);


            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                try {
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    BufferedReader in = null;
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                        String line = "";
                        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + NL);
                            lines+=line;
                        }
                        in.close();
                        return lines;

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

---

the above class is called from:

```
public String GetDataFromServer(String serverIP,String nvp) {   
     SimpleWebCalls tWebCall = new SimpleWebCalls();
     String sReturn="";
     sReturn= tWebCall.executeHttpGet(serverIP,nvp);
     return sReturn;
}
```

---

the above function is called from:

```
String data="";
data="doAction=location&u=" + sess.getUserName()+
    "&p=" + sess.getPwd() + 
    "&uid=" + sess.getUserID() + 
    "&lf=" + sess.encodeStr(editScannedCode.getText().toString());              
result = sess.GetDataFromServer(serverIP,data);
```

Comment: Attach Full code of java file

Comment: have updated the post with the full class minus the server IP address.

Comment: where you execute this executeHttpGet() method just post that Code.

Comment: i've added the calls to this class now.

Answer (score 0):

[follow this tutorial link](http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-asynctask-example-with-progress-bar) it might be helpful to you.

add GetDataFromServer() method in to your doInBackground() method.